# How to run this simple C++ program?

Tags: c++

I'm beginner in C++ and trying to run some starter code. I have the following files,

```
myTest.h
////////

#ifndef __myTest_h__
#define __myTest_h__

#include <string>

using std::string;

class myTest{

public:    
    int main(int, char const**);
}; 

#endif // __myArray_h__ 



myTest.cpp
//////////


#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include "myTest.h"
using namespace std;



int myTest::main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    std::cout<< "Hello World/n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run from the terminal in Mac OS using the command `g++ myTest.cpp -o myTest.out`, I get the following error in the terminal,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How to correct the code to getting started with C++? I can provide more info using the command `-v`, please, let me know if that required.

Comment: C++ is not Java

Comment: This should be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unlike Java or C# you can't have your `main` function in a class, it must be a global non-member function.

---

You can make a very simple `main` function which then calls your member function `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    myTest myTestObject;
    return myTestObject.main(argc, argv);
}
```

Note that I need to create an instance of the `myTest` class, this is because the `myTest::main` function is not made `static`. If you make it `static`, like

```
class myTest
{
public:
    static int main(int, char *[]);
    ...
};
```

then your non-member `main` function could look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return myTest::main(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it working now. Why do they keep the `main` out of the class in C++?

Comment: @Arefe Backwards compatibility is one reason. Another is that you could have multiple classes and namespaces each having a `main` function, which should then be used?

Comment: So, in C++ the starting point will be the `main` method stays out of a class and that will be the one and only starting point even when we will have multiple classes, say, for developing a game with several characters ?

Comment: @Arefe Yes, the global, "free", stand-alone non-member function `main` is the only entry point. If you have e.g. a game with multiple characters then you have multiple instance of the single `Character` class, for example, and handle events related to each specific character, probably in some kind of loop.

Answer (score 3):

Your entry point `main` function cannot be inside a class. It has to be a normal function.

If you want to place your logic inside a class, have your `main` function allocate an instance of it and then call a function in it.

Answer (score 2):

Every C++ program needs a **main()** function, which is what the C++ startup code calls immediately after loading and initializing your program. So, you'll need to link your program with a .cpp file containing a main() function,

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

}
```

Comment: Constructors are called before **main()**

Answer (score 1):

You need an entry point for your program. You have to add `int main() {}` because that's your entry point and then call your member function in your class. It needs to be outside of a class or struct.